# Redirect 302 response ignored on linux server

Tags: php, apache, redirect, yii2

My Yii2/PHP server code returns a 302 redirect (all HTTPS) in response to a POST submit.

When seeing it on local windows localhost, it redirects to the new adress just fine.

Then I upload to one.com having a linux server and I can tell from console that a 302 response is returned, BUT the browser seems to **ignore it** and then issues a GET request to the adress of the form submission, which is just confusing.

The .htaccess and code is identical in both environments.

Where would I begin to look for the error?

Comment: Open the browser's network debug console (typically ctrl-shift-i) and inspect the headers  that are actually received from the POST request.

Comment: _"BUT the browser seems to ignore it and then issues a GET request to the adress of the form submission, which is just confusing."_ - not that confusing, when you read what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_redirection has to say about this.

Comment: Is the server configured to let .htaccess override server rules?

Comment: The response headers are (slightly modified):
HTTP/2 302 Found
date: Tue, 29 Aug 2023 13:56:36 GMT
server: Apache
x-powered-by: PHP/8.0.30
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
x-redirect: https://example.com/location/view?id=4998
 path=/; HttpOnly
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
location: 
x-varnish: 1229728317
age: 0
via: 1.1 webcache2 (Varnish/trunk)
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

Comment: Based the comments I tried in Edge where it actually does redirect correctly. So it seems to be a Firefox 117 problem.....

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If this is related to PHP, please share the code involved